# How to manually show CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton sub-menu?

Tags: c++, drop-down-menu, mfc, cmfctoolbar

Standard behaviour for [`CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-class?view=vs-2017) is to have a clickable button plus a drop-down arrow for displaying a submenu. I want to show the submenu independently of where the click was made. How can I do it?

My code to create the button is, more or less, the following (it has been extracted from a larger project, so I apologize for any missing not-too-important piece of code):

```
// In class declaration:
CMenu m_menu;
CMFCToolBar m_toolbar;

// Where toolbar initialization takes place:
m_menu.CreateMenu();
// ... populate menu

// ID_BUTTON is the ID in the resource file for the toolbar button, 0 is the index for the button icon
CMFCToolBarMenuButton button(ID_BUTTON, m_menu.GetSafeHmenu(), 0);
m_toolbar.ReplaceButton(ID_BUTTON, button);
```

I've been looking around for awhile and cannot find a related answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution happened to be very straightforward, just call the [`OnClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-class?view=vs-2017#onclick) function of the `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton` button from its associated `ON_COMMAND`.

```
// ... message map
ON_COMMAND(ID_BUTTON, OnToolbarMenuButtonClicked)
// ...

void MyWnd::OnToolbarMenuButtonClicked()
{
  const int index = m_toolbar.CommandToIndex(ID_BUTTON);
  auto button = (CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton*)m_toolbar.GetButton(index);
  button->OnClick(NULL, TRUE);
}
```

This behaviour is not documented and, contrary to what common sense told me, it doesn't create an infinite recursive call. It seems that the "main" button is still controlled by `CMFCToolBarButton`, while just the "arrow-button" is controlled by the `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton`.

PS: obviously, and out of the scope of the question, the `OnToolbarMenuButtonClicked` can be used for a very different purpose, such as the default action while the sub-menu contains other less-frequent options.