# How to programmatically show dropdown-menu of ribbon button?

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I have ribbon button with a set of sub-items added. Such items are displayed when the user clicks on the tiny arrow below the button. I'd like to display such dropdown-menu when the button itself is clicked. How can I do that?

My initial idea was to programmatically show the menu when the user clicks the button. I've been able to do the same on toolbars ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406608/1485885)) but using a similar solution on ribbons creates an infinite recursion:

```
// ...
ON_COMMAND(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, &MainFrame::OnButtonClicked)
// ...

CMFCRibbonPanel *panel = /* initialization */
CMFCRibbonButton *button = new CMFCRibbonButton(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, "Caption");
panel->Add(button);

CMFCRibbonButton *item1 = new CMFCRibbonButton(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, "Item 1");
button->AddSubItem(item1);
CMFCRibbonButton *item2 = new CMFCRibbonButton(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, "Item 2");
button->AddSubItem(item2);

// ...
void MainFrame::OnButtonClicked()
{
  if (auto button = static_cast<CMFCRibbonButton *>(m_ribbons.wndRibbonBar.FindByID(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON))) {

    // button->OnClick({}); // <- causes infinite recursion

    // What to do here?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I've found so far is to use the protected method `CMFCRibbonButton::OnShowPopupMenu`. It implies deriving the `CMFCRibbonButton` class and changing the visibility of the method:

```
#include <afxribbonbutton.h>

class CMyMFCRibbonButton : public CMFCRibbonButton {
public:
  using CMFCRibbonButton::CMFCRibbonButton;

  virtual void OnShowPopupMenu() override {
    CMFCRibbonButton::OnShowPopupMenu();
  }
};

// ...
ON_COMMAND(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, &MainFrame::OnButtonClicked)
// ...

CMFCRibbonPanel *panel = /* initialization */
CMyMFCRibbonButton *button = new CMyMFCRibbonButton(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, "Caption");
panel->Add(button);

CMFCRibbonButton *item1 = new CMFCRibbonButton(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, "Item 1");
button->AddSubItem(item1);
CMFCRibbonButton *item2 = new CMFCRibbonButton(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON, "Item 2");
button->AddSubItem(item2);

// ...
void MainFrame::OnButtonClicked()
{
  if (auto button = static_cast<CMyMFCRibbonButton*>(m_ribbons.wndRibbonBar.FindByID(ID_RIBBON_BUTTON))) {
    button->OnShowPopupMenu();
  }
}
```

Comment: By convention, MFC class members starting with `On` are event handlers. They are invoked in response to events (like messages) or called by the framework. They aren't meant to be called by user code.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, do you know a way to call it correctly? Maybe the message code to be sent?

Comment: @cbuchart You could use SendMessage(...).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage

Comment: I just checked the code for `CMFCRibbonButton` (afxribbonbutton.cpp) and it looks like MFC doesn't follow any particular convention. `CMFCRibbonButton::OnLButtonDown` does indeed call into `OnShowPopupMenu`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcribbonbaseelement-class#onshowpopupmenu) isn't entirely enlightening as to whether you should or should not call this method in your code. This may or may not be the way to go. If in doubt, you can request clarification at the bottom of the documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a blank pop-up submenu and attached to the button, the button will work as you requested, while displaying the buttons previously added as SubItems.

```cpp
CMenu map_menu;
map_menu.CreateMenu();

button->SetHMenu(map_menu.GetSafeHmenu());
```

Comment: I no longer have access to that project, but I appreciate your contribution, I will try to implement it at some moment, thanks!